# HTTP 503 Error occurred after completing upgrade from Dnn 9.1.1 to 9.3.0

Tags: dotnetnuke, dnn9

After Upgrading successfully by transferring upgrade zip file and completing upgrade wizard process after host login, Error HTTP 503 came up when I clicked on "Visit Website" button. After going through Log files below error log was found

```
DotNetNuke.Services.Exceptions.Exceptions - System.IndexOutOfRangeException: TermsTabId
   at System.Data.ProviderBase.FieldNameLookup.GetOrdinal(String fieldName)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.GetOrdinal(String name)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.get_Item(String name)
   at DotNetNuke.Entities.Portals.PortalInfo.Fill(IDataReader dr)
   at DotNetNuke.Common.Utilities.CBO.FillObjectFromReader(Object objObject, IDataReader dr)
```

Issue happened at Live site

Answer (score 1):

Going from DNN 9.1.1 to 9.3.2 (and maybe beyond that) requires some careful attention to detail.  In that series of releases, there are some important breaking changes, most of them related to the removal of APIs that have been deprecated since DNN 7.  Most of these issues can be solved by making sure that any modules you have added to the basic DNN Platform have been update prior to doing the upgrades.  Essentially, you'll want to make sure that your modules (and possibly skins) are compatible with the DNN version to which you are upgrading.

Read the release notes for all of the intermediate releases, especially 9.3.1 and 9.3.2.  There are some important breaking changes to DNN.

Also read the notes at the bottom of https://dnndocs.com/content/getting-started/setup/upgrades/suggested-upgrade-path/index.html

Before doing the upgrade, you should identify any modules that need to be upgraded because of breaking changes and removal of deprecated APIs.

If you need additional help with this, I'd recommended visiting the forums at dnncommunity.org and asking questions there.  Among other things, you may find that the community of people who can help is larger over there.

Comment: I had already done these steps during staging upgrade and it was a success. But during live site upgrade this happened which was unexpected

Comment: @EjazHasnain Was the upgrade that worked done on a clone/copy of the production site?